# Difference between emit() and emit(socket.id) in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm really bad at web development buy I'm trying to figure out how webrtc works
They have this code on their official guide

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  // convenience function to log server messages on the client
  function log() {
    var array = ['Message from server:'];
    array.push.apply(array, arguments);
    socket.emit('log', array); // this
  }

  socket.on('create or join', function(room) {
    if (numClients === 0) {
      socket.join(room);
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room);
      socket.emit('created', room, socket.id); //this

    }
  });
});
```

What is the difference between `socket.emit('log', array);` and `socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);`

The signature is different, but it seems like this functions do the same - send some info back to the caller? Please help me to understand. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args

Comment: It's just another argument, you can pass as many as you want